# Ember modal only shows overlay

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm having trouble showing a modal with Ember. I've followed the cookbook but when I click the button for the modal, it only shows the overlay and not the modal itself.

Here's my gist: https://gist.github.com/sunocean-sand/e11111cea44274417012

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a similar implementation in one of my apps.  Try changing your `routes/application.js` to the code below.  I believe your problem is that you're not using Bootstrap's [Programmatic API](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api).

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal: function(modal) {
      this.render(modal, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
      return Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {
        Ember.$('.modal').modal('show');
      });
    },

    closeModal: function() {
      Ember.$('.modal').modal('hide');
      return this.disconnectOutlet({
        outlet: 'modal',
        parentView: 'application'
      });
    }
  }
});
```